# Show progress of calculations in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was wondering how to show the progress of a ggplot2 or ggmap operation while it is calculating. I'm working with some very large shapefiles and they can take several minutes to display the plot. I know there are several packages and functions that allow you to insert a progress bar or percentage during a calculation (eg. the "progress" package), but I can't figure out how to insert it inside the ggplot operation.

So, example below:

```
library (ggplot2)
library (sf)
     
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = "myshapefile.shp", size = 1, color = "black", fill = "red") + 
  ggtitle("Testplot") + 
  coord_sf()
```

This shapefile takes several minutes to render into a plot. Rather than just sitting there waiting for it to show up and not knowing when it will finish or if it is stuck. I would like to see some kind of progress (bar or percentage, doesn't matter - eg. showing when it is 10%, 20%, 30%, etc. done).

Comment: Interesting question. You  probably need to interact with the ggplot code to achieve this. Something similar to what `pblappy` from the `pbapply` packages does.

Comment: That progress updating would need to be built into the plotting functions themselves which it is not. This is not something you could do without changing the source code of the ggplot functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hadley Wickham, the creator of ggplot2, says a progress bar is not possible here.

[image]

His suggestion to simplify the shapefile will remove vertices to a certain tolerance, and will usually make it render faster without any perceivable difference in the figure. It can be done like so.

```
library (ggplot2)
library (sf)
my_shapefile <- read_sf("myshapefile.shp")

# You'll have to test different tolerance levels here. Higher
# values will produce more rigid looking shapes which will render faster. 
# I would try values of 0.01, 0.1, 1, and 10.
my_shapefile <- st_simplify(my_shapefile, dTolerance = 0.1)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = my_shapefile, size = 1, color = "black", fill = "red") + 
  ggtitle("Testplot") + 
  coord_sf()
```